# Python split by multiple separators, including space?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input:

```
Some Text here: Java, PHP, JS, HTML 5, CSS, Web, C#, SQL, databases, AJAX, etc.
```

Code:

```
import re

input_words = list(re.split('\s+', input()))
print(input_words)
```

Works perfect and returns me:

```
['Some', 'Text', 'here:', 'Java,', 'PHP,', 'JS,', 'HTML', '5,', 'CSS,', 'Web,', 'C#,', 'SQL,', 'databases,', 'AJAX,', 'etc.']
```

But when add some other separators, like this:

```
import re

input_words = list(re.split('\s+ , ; : . ! ( ) " \' \ / [ ] ', input()))
print(input_words)
```

It doesn't split by spaces anymore, where am I wrong?

**Expected outpus would be:**

```
['Some', 'Text', 'here', 'Java', 'PHP', 'JS', 'HTML', '5', 'CSS', 'Web', 'C#', 'SQL', 'databases', 'AJAX', 'etc']
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be splitting on a regex *alternation* containing all those symbols:

```
input_words = re.split('[\s,;:.!()"\'\\\[\]]', input())
print(input_words)
```

This is a literal answer to your question.  The actual solution you might want to use would be to split on the symbols with optional whitespace on either end, e.g

```
input = "A B ; C.D   ! E[F] G"
input_words = re.split('\s*[,;:.!()"\'\\\[\]]?\s*', input)
print(input_words)
```

Prints:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
```

Comment: It returns me empty elements, probably `trim` after all ?

Comment: First solution works with `list(filter(None, input_words))` this row also.

Comment: Without seeing all your sample data, we can only guess, but see my updated answer for a possible solution.

Comment: Then my second suggestion is probably along the lines of what you should be doing, namely splitting on symbols with whitespace before/after them.

Comment: It's edit with expected output, so your first solution + `list(filter(None, input_words))` works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

write the expression inside brackets as shown below. Hope it helps

```
import re



input_words = list(re.split('[\s+,:.!()]', input()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Word tokenization using nltk module

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import nltk

sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning
... Arthur didn't feel very good."""
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sentence)
print(words)
```

**output:**

> ['At', 'eight', "o'clock", 'on', 'Thursday', 'morning', '...',
>   'Arthur', 'did', "n't", 'feel', 'very', 'good', '.']